Get part of the web-address
I need to extract the actual filename from an URL.

https://www.corp.com/lib/file.html?id=aa
https://www.corp.com/lib/file.html?id=aa/bb
https://www.corp.com/lib/file.html

Expected result: file.html in all cases. Note: The filename does not need to have a dot, it could be just file and that should return file as result then.
In the case of

https://www.corp.com/lib/
https://www.corp.com/lib/?id=aa
https://www.corp.com/lib/?id=aa/bb

Expected result should be ""
Been testing with regex now for some time but just can't get the grouping to work coz of the existing (or not) questionmark. I know that the frontslash in the query is most likely not going to happen but if it is possible I would like to take it in consideration as well due to that the webbrowser seems to accept it without encoding it.
I can't do it programmatically in steps becauase the tool I use only handle regex.
Any ideas here?

...what language are you using? Pretty much every language out there has a URI-parsing library. You should use that instead of a regex, if possible - because otherwise your regex will be tripped-up by filename-looking-substrings in, say, the username part, or if there's a hostname that looks like a filename - e.g. https://file.html:file.html:file.html/file.html/file.html?filehtml=file.html is a valid URI, y'see (if file.html is defined in your DNS server)

"I can't do it programmatically in steps becauase the tool I use only handle regex.": what tool is that? So is it a tool that takes, say, two arguments, a URL and a regex?

@Dai This is actually not any language, it's a tool for textexpanders :-)

like so: (?<=(?<!\/)\/)\w+\.\w+(?=$|\?)?

Do you care about "non-obvious" urls like https://corp.com/lib/? Or https://corp.com/lib/file.html/? Or https://corp.com/lib.

@JoachimSauer thank you so much for noticing thet, my bad! yes, if the "filename" is missing, then the result should be en empty string "". I've updated the question.

@DuesserBaest that's so awesome :-) thank you so much, I did make an error in my question though, very sorry. The "filename" do not need to have a dot . in it. It could be "http://corp.com/filename" without a dot. Very sorry for the missing case.

then how do you know that bb in https://www.corp.com/lib/?id=aa/bb is not a file?

@DuesserBaest the optional question mark and everything following it can always be ignored. Sorry for the bad description.

Try:
^.*\K(?<=(?<!\/)\/)[.\w]+(?=\?)|([^?\n]*\?[^?\n]*)(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|[.\w]+$

See: regex101

Explanation:
there are three cases:

the file is in front of the ?:


^.*\K: from the start of the string match everything and forget it up unil...
(?<!\/)\/)[.\w]+(?=\?): you find a string preceeded by one / but not two // and succeeded by ?


you have a sting containing a ?


([^?\n]*\?[^?\n]*): if the string contains a questionmark...
(*SKIP)(*FAIL): discard it


your desired sting is at the end of line:


[.\w]+$


This is a very good answer :-) although I was not clear in the question, the "filename" does not need to have a dot in it. Verry sorry for the poor description. It feels like it should just be to change the \w.\w part but then it breaks and matching other parts. :-)

@steb can you access capture groups? do you have access to branch reset groups? try (?|^.*(?<=(?<!\/)\/)(\w+\.\w+)(?=\?)|([^?\n]*\?[^?\n]*)(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|([.\w]+)$); results would be in group 1

Or if you can use \K ^.*\K(?<=(?<!\/)\/)[.\w]+(?=\?)|([^?\n]*\?[^?\n]*)(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|[.\w]+$ would work

That's AWESOME, the last one with \K works perfect. Thank you so much @DuesserBaest. You're the king in regex!

It can be shorten to ^[^#?]*/\K[^/?#]*(?![^#?])

@CasimiretHippolyte yes you're absolutely right , that seems to work just fine as well :-) just escaping the front slashes and it works in my case. Very nice done!

For use with PCRE maybe like this could suffice:
^[^?]*\/\K[\w.-]*

See this demo at regex101 (\n in the demo is just  for multiline testing)
The idea is to match any characters that are not ? up to the last slash. With \K reset beginning of the reported match and from there match any amount of word-characters, dot, dash (also empty).
But if you don't want empty matches and use [\w.-]+ this would not work (demo) because of backtracking. To make it work you could use the PCRE verb COMMIT to do not backtrack after having matched the last slash. Proabably also SKIP could be used instead with a similar effect.
^[^?]*\/(*COMMIT)\K[\w.-]+

Another demo at regex101 (@DuesserBaest I borrowed your showcase)
